# compose selecting and highlighting the column that has been clicked

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have the following code that represents the days of week. However, when the user selects a day it highlights whole rectangle. However, I just want to highight oval shape not the entire area as below.

The currently selected day is Friday and I have just clicked the Wednesday. It should just highlight the oval shape.

Individual button

```
@Composable
fun CalendarDayButton(
    date: ZonedDateTime,
    isSelected: Boolean,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onSelected: (date: ZonedDateTime) -> Unit) {

    val backgroundColor = if(isSelected) Orange else White
    val fontDayColor = if(isSelected) DarkGray else Gray

    Column(modifier = modifier
        .background(color = backgroundColor, shape = RoundedCornerShape(100.dp))
        .clickable {
            onSelected(date)
        },
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {

        Text(text = date.dayOfWeek.name.first().toString(), fontSize = 12.sp, color = fontDayColor)
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
        Text(text = date.dayOfMonth.toString(), fontSize = 16.sp, color = DarkGray,  fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
    }
}

@Composable
@Preview(showBackground = true)
fun PreviewDayDateButtonSelected() {
    BusbyTaskyTheme {
        CalendarDayButton(
            date = ZonedDateTime.now(),
            isSelected = true,
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(color = Orange, shape = RoundedCornerShape(100.dp))
                .size(width = 40.dp, height = 60.dp),
            onSelected = {
            }
        )
    }
}
```

The whole 6 days

```
@Composable
fun AgendaDaySelector(
    date: ZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(),
    isSelectedDay: ZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(),
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onSelected: (ZonedDateTime) -> Unit,
) {
    Row(
        modifier = modifier,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly) {

        (0L..6L).forEach { day ->
            CalendarDayButton(
                modifier = Modifier.background(color = Orange, shape = RoundedCornerShape(100.dp))
                    .size(width = 40.dp, height = 60.dp),
                date = date.plusDays(day),
                isSelected = isSelectedDay.dayOfWeek == date.plusDays(day).dayOfWeek,
                onSelected = { date ->
                    onSelected(date)
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
@Preview(showBackground = true)
fun PreviewAgendaDaySelector() {
    BusbyTaskyTheme {
        var selectedDay by remember {
            mutableStateOf(ZonedDateTime.now())
        }

        AgendaDaySelector(
            date = ZonedDateTime.now(),
            isSelectedDay = selectedDay,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            onSelected = {
                selectedDay = it
            }
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Modifier.drawbackground(color, shape)` does not clip to your current shape. shape of layer can be changed by

```
Modifier.clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(100.dp)) which is

fun Modifier.clip(shape: Shape) = graphicsLayer(shape = shape, clip = true)
```

or as in decleration of clip calling `Modifier.graphicsLayer(shape, true)` or

```
Modifier.graphicsLayer {
   clip = true
   shape = RoundedCornerShape(100.dp)
}
```

This might be the case for this question but when you set a shape it also determines touch boundaries of that Composable. For example, if you set a `CircleShape` touching only inside that circle will invoke touch actions and ripple propagation.